# Book in the gay/BDSM/crime genre where the main character is a police officer

Tags: identification-request

Some time ago I read a series that had two books, in the gay/BDSM genre, and also the crime genre. I don't remember the title or the author and with the few details I know, I can't find it. I think it does not exist in physical form and there is only a Kindle version.

The story in the first book is how the main character, who is a police officer must infiltrate somewhere on a case (I don't remember where it was, but it was related to BDSM), and they assign him a partner (who I think was a teacher, I'm not sure), who prepares him for the case, since I think "the partner" was involved in the world of BDSM.

And the second book is I think about their relationship, also with related to BDSM. The only scene I remember from the second book is where I think the protagonist "police officer" is drugged and pushed into a pool (trying to kill him) or something like that. His partner doesn't believe him and thinks he fell because he was drunk. I think they were at a BDSM club at the time, investigating a series of murders.

Comment: Those are some good details. Did you download the MOBI files? Get it via the Kindle store? Download it via Kindle Unlimited? Rent it from your library?

Comment: Could it be [Intimate bondage](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22580972-intimate-bondage), the first book in the [Kate Dawson](https://www.goodreads.com/series/250390-kate-dawson) series?